# How to simplify an array by removing numbers that are close to each other in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with some numbers

```
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
```

how do I remove numbers that are close to each other less than or equal to `0.2` threshold and put the average of those values instead,
so the above array becomes

```
[0.2, 0.8]
```

`0.2` because `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` are close to each other so they become `(0 + 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3) / 4 = 0.2`

`0.8` because `[0.6, 0.8, 1]` are close to each other so they become `(0.6, 0.8, 1) / 2 = 0.8`

Comment: Please clarify the actual criteria for removing. Why would the result be `[0.2, 0.8]`?

Comment: Search for "clustering" because that's what you are after

Comment: What happens if you have 0,0.1,0.2,0.3,...,0.8,0.9,1? Each neighbor is only 0.1 away from the next? Will they collapse to a single 0.5 value?

Comment: yes it doesn't matter

Comment: and it doesn't even have to be average if you can further simplify just a value in between those numbers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by iterating over every element of the array and keeping a temporary `close` array. If `close` is empty, or the current element and the last element in `close`'s difference is less than the threshold, then you can add it to `close`. If not, then average `close` and add it to the output array. Note that floating point math gets a bit weird here, you can use [this rounding trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644302/13376511).

```js
const fixFloat = n => parseFloat(n.toPrecision(12))

function average(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const el of arr) sum += el;
  return fixFloat(sum / arr.length);
}

function closeRemove(arr, threshold) {
  arr = [...arr].sort()
  const res = [];
  let close = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const diff = fixFloat(arr[i] - close[close.length-1]);
    if (close.length == 0 || diff <= threshold) {
      close.push(arr[i])
    } else {
      res.push(average(close));
      close = [arr[i]];
    }
  }
  res.push(average(close));
  return res;
}

const arr = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 1];
console.log(closeRemove(arr, 0.2));
```

Note that in your question, the numbers `0`, `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3` all have a difference of less than `0.2`, so they should be averaged together. Their average is `1.5`, not `2`.

Comment: `0.15` rounded to 1 place after the comma is `0.2`

Comment: @derpirscher Does OP ask for averages to be rounded to one place after the decimal? I can't see it in the question or any comments.

Comment: Not explicitly, but the example seems to point in that direction ...